# email css ruby help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, email

I am pulling emails into my ruby on rails web app and displaying them from users to see and reply etc within my app.

Problem is the emails css when displaying the email effects my sites css and visa versa.

Any one know the best solutition to the problem ?

Can use an iframe i suppost but dont think secure ?

cheers
Rick

Answer (score 0):

An `<iframe>` is the only solution I can see that will work reliably. If you display the E-Mail in your page's body, there is always the danger of CSS styles overriding each other.

There shouldn't be any security issues in using an `<iframe>` per se; you will have to be careful to filter out any JavaScript content before displaying the E-Mail on the site to avoid scripting attacks. But that applies whether you use Iframes or not.